# Javascript - How to insert html template and use variables in it

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder how can I insert html template into a javascript function and use variables in it, like for example here, where I am creating html and inserting variables to it. I would like to know how can I make it cleaner and have a template in a separate file and then use it in the function.

```
      {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Videos</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myUrl/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + '<small><abbr class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</abbr></small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
```

Comment: Search for templating systems, such as Handlebars, Mustache, ... This is also commonly a feature of higher-level libraries/frameworks like Knockout, React, Angular, Vue, Ember, ...

Comment: ATM, my favorite is [pug](https://pugjs.org).